# How to avoid the handshaking(mutual SSL) on every request fired from Jersey client

Tags: ssl, jersey

I am expecting that client will hadshake only in first request and any other subsequent request will result  with data transfer. How can we configure keep-alive with Jersy client or How can we use SSLSession?We are using Jersey 1.2 in our project.

Comment: It should happen by default, assuming your server is appropriately configured. Do you have some evidence that it isn't happening?

Comment: yes..When I am trying to hit the server using same Jersey client , it is handshaking every time . I have enabled the ssl log  by System.setProperty("javax.net.debug", "ssl:handshake"); , hits the same request twice ,log shows the handshaking twice .  What is required to configure the server properly to handle the handshake?

Comment: There is always a handshake: a long one or a short one. Does it show a *complete* handshake every time? All you need at the sever is to not turn SSL session resumption off: it is, again, on by default in every server I've used. You don't state *which* server, so further detail is impossible to provide.

Comment: It is showing the full handshake every time. We are using Apache server .